# python swaping values using comma is causing confusions

Tags: python, python-3.x, swap

this involves a problem that I encountered when try to solve a linked-list reverse problem.

First let me put some preliminary codes for the definition of the linked list and quick method to generate a linked list:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.next:
            return "{}->{}".format(self.val, repr(self.next))
        else:
            return "{}".format(self.val)

def genNode(*nodes, end=None):
    if len(nodes) == 1 and type(nodes[0]) == list:
        nodes = nodes[0]
    for i in nodes[::-1]:
        n = ListNode(i)
        n.next, end = end, n
    return n if nodes else None
```

The problem I have is that I found the swapping mechanism is still depending on the sequence of the variable that I write.

Originally when we talk about swapping values in python we can do:

```
a, b = b, a
```

and it should work the same way if I have

```
b, a = a, b
```

This reverse linked list method that I am trying to write has 3 variables swapping, the idea is simple, to create a dummy head, and consistently adding nodes between dummy and dummy.next, so that it can be reversed.

```
def rev(head):
    dummy = ListNode('X')
    while head:
        dummy.next, head.next, head = head, dummy.next, head.next
    return dummy.next

a = genNode(1,2,3,4)
print(rev(a)) # >>> 4->3->2->1
```

But If I slightly switch the sequence of the 3 variables:

```
def rev2(head):
    dummy = ListNode('X')
    while head:
        dummy.next, head, head.next, = head, head.next, dummy.next,
    return dummy.next

a = genNode(1,2,3,4)
print(rev2(a))  # >>> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

So it does seem like that the sequence matters here, and can anyone let me know how python evaluate swapping values if there is more than 2 variables.

Thanks!

Comment: which version of python?

Comment: it is python 3.6.4

Comment: Really, just don't do that. `a, b = b, a` is fine for simple swaps, but for anything more complicated, just write separate assignment statements.

Comment: The data types you are swapping are not simple basic datatypes, but a class object involving links to other objects, which can lead to unexpected behaviours like these!

Comment: @chepner  I plan to do that from now on. I didn't know that this can happen. Always thought that everything is evaluated at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

left to right

Look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

CPython implementation detail: In the current implementation, the syntax for targets is taken to be the same as for expressions, and invalid syntax is rejected during the code generation phase, causing less detailed error messages.

Although the definition of assignment implies that overlaps between the left-hand side and the right-hand side are ‘simultaneous’ (for example a, b = b, a swaps two variables), overlaps within the collection of assigned-to variables occur left-to-right, sometimes resulting in confusion. For instance, the following program prints [0, 2]:

```
x = [0, 1]
i = 0
i, x[i] = 1, 2         # i is updated, then x[i] is updated
print(x)
```

Comment: To tie it back to OP's example: in `rev()`, `head` is changed *after* `head.next` is assigned to; in `rev2`, `head` is changed *before*, thus altering what gets assigned to.

Comment: that is interesting, and if I try `x[i], i = 2, 1 ` it will actually work. So the sequence matters, but can be confusing.

Comment: So, (C)Python iterates over the `tuple` of values on the RHS and assigns them to the `tuple` of names on the LHS, elementwise and thus sequentially? If you interpret the comma-seperated list as a `tuple`, this modus operandi seems to be quite logical.

Comment: So would you suggest, that I should go back to classic swapping method by creating temporary variables, to be safe, when get into complicate/multiple swapping situations?

Comment: Similar to not changing a `list` you are iterating over, you probably should avoid assigning to names which can affect other assignments in the same assignment statement, like in the example. The example is very much constructed, I have not seen such code, ever.

Comment: As you can see in a simpler example, applying swap logic to a list is not very consistent and hence the old temporary variable is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

A simple example below should show you the caveat of using swapping for a class like `ListNode`

Let's define a 3 element linked list.

```
a = ListNode(1)
b = ListNode(2)
c = ListNode(3)
a.next = b
b.next = c
print(a)
#1->2->3
```

Now if we swap say b and c, it won't have any effect

```
b,c = c,b
print(a)
#1->2->3
```

If we swap a and b, the linked list changes.

```
a,b=b,a
print(a)
#2->3
```

Similarly for a and c swap.

```
a,c=c,a
print(a)
#3
```

So you can see that using the simple swap logic is inconsistent in how it applies to a `ListNode`, hence should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good demonstration. I should avoid using swap method in complicate data structures.

Comment: Great, please consider upvoting the example if it helped you, since you already accepted another answer!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting discussion, kind of extending the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55850513/8071529), I created this new example below.

```
x = [1, 0]
i = 0
i, x[i] = x[i], i
print(i, x)
>> 1 [1, 0]
```

Let's go through step by step to see what is going one with `i, x[i] = x[i], i`.

1. Initially, all variables are at the previous stage, i.e., `i=0`, so `x[i]` is `x[0]=1` for both sides. We have 0, x[0] = x[0], 0 or 0, 1 = 1, 0
2. The exchange/assignment starts from left to right. The left part of comma,`i = x[i]` takes place first, that is `i = 1`, `i` value changes from 0 to 1.
3. Importantly, when the right part of comma takes place, the value of `i` already changed. We are actually looking at, `1, x[1] = 1, 0`, the confusing part is that the `i` on the right will not change and its value is still 0, not the new value, `1, x[1] = 1, i`. Thus, the final state is,  `1, x[1] = 1, 0`.

Answer (score -1):

If there are more than two variables it works identically as with two. You put them in the desired final order:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> c,b,a = a,b,c
>>> a,b,c
(3, 2, 1)
```