# Value assignment

Tags: python, list, indexing

Can you explain how this value assignment works, it confused me?

```
my_list = [10, 1, 8, 3, 5]
length = len(my_list)

for i in range(length // 2):
    my_list[i], my_list[length - i - 1] = my_list[length - i - 1], my_list[i]

print(my_list)
```

let's also take even simple one :

```
variable_1 = 1
variable_2 = 2

variable_1, variable_2 = variable_2, variable_1
```

How has var1 changed it's value to var2 which is 2, and then var2 taken the value of var1, that's already been changed to var2. I hope my confused is clear. Is it because it works in parallel with each other?.

Comment: Looks duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850332/python-swaping-values-using-comma-is-causing-confusions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python swaping values using comma is causing confusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55850332/python-swaping-values-using-comma-is-causing-confusions)

Comment: The right hand side is actually a tuple that is unpacked into the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

This is called iterable unpacking. Please search about this. This is not only in Python. Few other languages like javascript also support this (it is called destructuring in that case). It doesn't use parallel exactly. Basically, python handles it by keeping an extra variable.

Comment: Nitpick: this is actually not called destructuring in Python, that would be Javascript. This is called *iterable unpacking* in Python.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Good to know